# Removing whitespace between nav-item dropdown, default behavior not working properly

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I'm trying to add the bootstrap menu on the header in the application, almost everything is ok, but when using on `<nav>` the `<li class='nav-item dropdown'>`, it adds an empty space and doesn't collapse on responsive mode.

I added a simple menu with brand on right side, with the following structure:

```
>Menu
--Home
--Link
--Dropdown
---Action
---Another action
---Something else
--Another dropdown
---Action
---Another action
---Something else
--Disabled
>Brand
```

In desktop mode, the menu is being shown properly.

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-light bg-light">
        <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarSupportedContent" aria-controls="navbarSupportedContent" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
            <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
        </button>
    
        <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarSupportedContent">
            <ul class="navbar-nav mr-auto">
                <li class="nav-item active">
                    <a class="nav-link" href="#">Home <span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a>
                </li>
                <li class="nav-item">
                    <a class="nav-link" href="#">Link</a>
                </li>
                <li class="nav-item dropdown">
                    <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" href="#" id="navbarDropdown" role="button" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
                        Dropdown
                    </a>
                    <div class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="navbarDropdown">
                        <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Action</a>
                        <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Another action</a>
                        <div class="dropdown-divider"></div>
                        <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Something else here</a>
                    </div>
                </li>
                <li class="nav-item dropdown">
                    <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" href="#" id="navbarDropdown" role="button" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
                        Another dropdown
                    </a>
                    <div class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="navbarDropdown">
                        <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Action</a>
                        <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Another action</a>
                        <div class="dropdown-divider"></div>
                        <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Something else here</a>
                    </div>
                </li>
                <li class="nav-item">
                    <a class="nav-link disabled" href="#">Disabled</a>
                </li>
            </ul>
            <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Navbar</a>
        </div>
    </nav>
```

My output needs to be like this:

[image: Target]

Instead, I'm getting this:

[image: Current]

Answer (score 0):

Try to edit them in CSS.

```
.nav-item{
    line-height: normal;
 }
```

Comment: Tks for the reply, I added this snippet, it has been applied but with no practical effect, even added a !important in the end of line :-(

Answer (score 0):

It seems you want to block the space of your disabled element, but not showing it.
With this condition you can't just `display: none;` but use any sort of work-arround.
You could get the trick simple with adding css:

```
.disabled { opacity: 0;}
```

As you can see in this Codepen:
https://codepen.io/anon/pen/dBzYNg

EDIT: I don't know how to change view width in codepen, but you can use developer tools to change the browser view or pull the border between code and preview so that preview is like mobile width.

Comment: This snippet just sets the .disabled element opacity to zero. The space size is the exact size of "hidden" <a> dropdown-item.

Comment: Ah, didn't see your "Disabled" text in your wanted-image, it has low contrast. Maybe you use some local stylesheet in your browser? since your basic code works as you want it on codepen and at my local machine.